# DBMS MYSQL using 'insert' so that it asks for the values

Tags: mysql

Please show me an example where I can use `insert` in MYSQL such that it asks for the values to enter by the user. I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO sometable value
(&pname,&dob);
```

but it showed an error.

Comment: `INSERT INTO tableName (stringCol, intCol, dateCol) VALUES ('a', 1, '2013-01-01 00:00:00')` -- basic syntax insert statement.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have any built-in user-prompting. You need to write an application in some other language, and have it construct the `INSERT` query to send to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

check this,

```
INSERT INTO urTable(col1,col2) VALUES(v1,v2), (v3,v4), (v5,v6)
```

Comment: How will that _ask for the values to enter by user_?

Comment: you will need to write a program to that user prompting part. this query will then help you to add the records to mysql db table

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do user prompting in MYSQL.

Here is the syntax for inserting data:-

```
INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2) VALUES('data1', 'data2' )
```

Example:-

```
INSERT INTO phonebook(phone, firstname, lastname, address) VALUES('+1 123 456 7890', 'John', 'Doe', 'North America')
```